# Coloring image components according to their area

Tags: image-processing

I have a rasterized image `img` that is created by this code:

```
img =  
   Image @ 
      Graphics[
        {Disk[], Disk[{4, 4}, 1.5], Disk[{-4, 5}, 2], Disk[{0, -6}, 4]},
        PlotRange -> 11]
```

[image]

I want to color the circles depending on their size (near white for the biggest, going through darker grays until the smallest gets colored black, or something similar).

I know it has something to do with `MorphologicalComponents`, but I don't know how to colorize the different components.

**EDIT:**

Actually the input image was not the circle one, it was this:

[image]

And when I run your code, even though the points image gets good results, this one gives some error. The output is this:

[image]

Which doesn't recognize the areas of any squares.

Comment: `Colorize[m=MorphologicalComponents[ColorNegate@Binarize@img], 
 ColorRules -> 
  Join[{0 -> White}, 
   Thread[SortBy[ComponentMeasurements[m, "FilledCount"], Last][[All, 
       1]] -> GrayLevel /@ {.1, .6, .8, .9}]]]` - fiddle with values to taste...

Comment: @ciao Any way this can be extended for n objects instead of given 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ArrayPlot

```
ArrayPlot[MorphologicalComponents[ColorNegate[i]]]
```

[image]

or you can use a `ColorFunction`. Here is a version for the second input image with the smaller regions using darker colors.

```
mimg = MorphologicalComponents[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4FkO.png"]];
map = Thread[
   Ordering@ComponentMeasurements[mimg, "Area"][[All, 2]] -> 
    Range[Max[mimg]]];
areas = mimg /. map;
Colorize[areas, ColorFunction -> "GrayTones"]
```

[image]

Comment: I actually do care about the colors. I want the smallest circle to be black, and the biggest circle white, and the middle ones with a level of gray, depending on its area.

Comment: Even as revised doesn't give the correct color dependency on area.

Comment: With that last method, I noticed the colors goes from white to black starting from top to bottom. I actually need them to be in order from the smallest to the biggest.

Comment: I believe I've fixed the "direction" of the colors.

Answer (score 4):

I started with ciao's code, but I didn't like the way the gray level values were obtained, so I re-worked his code to this:

```
img = 
  Image @ 
    Graphics[
      {Disk[], Disk[{4, 4}, 1.5], Disk[{-4, 5}, 2], Disk[{0, -6}, 4]},
      PlotRange -> 11]

With[{m = MorphologicalComponents[ColorNegate @ Binarize @ img]},
   Module[{items, n, areas, lvls},
     items = ComponentMeasurements[m, "FilledCount"];
     n = Length @ items;
     areas = items[[All, 2]];
     lvls = 
       Thread[
         Rule[
           Range @ n, 
           GrayLevel @ Sqrt @ Rescale[#, MinMax[areas], {.05, .85}] & /@ areas]];
     Colorize[m, ColorRules -> Join[{0 -> White}, lvls]]]]
```

[image: colorized]

Comment: I changed "FilledCount" with "Elongation" and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for my poor English to may be failure understand demand of your question.And as I understand the curently accepted answer have not at par slightly?

---

- **The first question**

> color the circles depending on their size (near white for the biggest,
>   going through darker grays until the smallest gets colored black, or
>   something similar)

This is my solution

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqRZd.png"] // ColorNegate;
MorphologicalComponents[img] // 
 Colorize[#, 
   ColorRules -> 
    Prepend[Normal[
      Blend[{Black, 
          White}, #] & /@ (ComponentMeasurements[img, "Area"] // 
          Association // (# - Min[#])/(Max[#] - Min[#]) &)], 
     0 -> Red]] &
```

[image]

(*I set the background red is for conveniently looking the circle of White to Black,otherwise your white circle will be invisible.*)

---

- **The second question**

> Which doesn't recognize the areas of any squares.

So you just colorize the squares or I take a wrong interpretation?But those place isn't a squres?

[image]

So I post a solution like follow

```
array = MorphologicalComponents[
   pic = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4FkO.png"]];
effect = SelectComponents[
   array, {"PerimeterLength", 
    "EquivalentDiskRadius"}, #/#2 - (4*Sqrt[Pi] // N) <= 2.8 &] // 
  Colorize[#, 
    ColorRules -> 
     Prepend[Normal[
       Blend[{Black, 
           White}, #] & /@ (ComponentMeasurements[#, "Area"] // 
           Association // (# - Min[#])/(Max[#] - Min[#]) &)], 
      0 -> Red]] &
```

[image]

```
ImageCompose[pic, {effect, 0.8}]
```

[image]